# Find all the central extensions of $\Bbb{Z}_2$ by $\Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}_2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Find all the central extensions of $\Bbb{Z}_2$ by $\Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}_2$.

At first I was going to say that, since central extensions mean a trivial homomorphism, there must be only one: $\Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}_2$. However, only split extensions are semidirect products, and we don't know if a section exists for all the groups G that contain a normal subgroup of order 2 and satisfy the surjective homomorphism $f: G \rightarrow \Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}_2$ with kernel $\Bbb{Z}_2$, right? So I tried to take a different approach.

We know that the groups of order 8 are $\Bbb{Z}_8$, $D_8$, $Q_8$, $\Bbb{Z}_4 \times \Bbb{Z}_2$, and $\Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}_2$. So we need to check which one of these contain a normal subgroup of order 2, and they all do, right? So we need to check if we can come up with a surjective homomorphism from these groups to $\Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}_2$ with kernel $\Bbb{Z}_2$. But that's also true for all of these groups, and so they must be all the possible central extensions, right?

I'm just asking to see if my understanding is correct.

Thank you in advance

Comment: We usually call $G$ a central extension of $Q$ by $K$ if $Q \cong G / K$.

Comment: "that's also true for all of these groups" - check this again!

Comment: @SteveD This is true for only 3 groups, right? $\Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}_2$, $\Bbb{Z}_4 \times \Bbb{Z}_2$, and $D_8$.

Comment: @SammyBlack But isn't $Q \cong G/K$ true for all extensions? I'm a bit confused, because this is what my [textbook](http://www.albany.edu/~mark/algebra.pdf) says when it introduces extensions "Here, loosely, we study all groups G that contain a given group H as a normal subgroup, such that the factor group G/H is isomorphic to a particular group K. This is the first step in trying to classify composition series."